# Python random.expovariate() zero division error

Tags: python, numpy, random, simpy

When I use random.expovariate(1/6) in my code, i get zero divison error. Anyone knows why? This is my code:

```
randomSeed = 1000
random.seed(randomSeed)    
def function1(env):
    for i in range(1000):
        time = random.expovariate(1/6)
        yield env.timeout(time)
```

This is the error:

```
File "..\simulation.py", line 108, in function1
    time = random.expovariate(1/6)
File "..\random.py", line 440, in expovariate
    return -_log(1.0 - self.random())/lambd
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to debug

- The last line of your error message says `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero`.
- Above that it says this happened on line 440 of `expovariate`, when it tried to evaluate `return -_log(1.0 - self.random())/lambd`.  The only division there is by `lambd`.
- If you go to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) for `expovariate`, you'll notice that `lambd` is the argument to the function, where the first error message tells you you've put `1/6`.  Q.e.d. `1/6` must be zero.  You can enter an interactive Python session to confirm.
- At that point, recall or look up how integer division works to come up with the solution that changing `1/6` to use floats will do what you want.

Some error messages can be pretty arcane, but they're there to explain why, where, and how things failed to the best of the languages ability.  Reading them and following the chain back is a skill well worth learning.

Answer (score 4):

`random.expovariate()` input should be non-zero. I'm guessing you're running python2 and `1/6` is 0. Change it to `1./6.` and it should be fine.